# "secret" option required for "app.use(express.cookieSession())"

Tags: node.js, express

The [website](http://expressjs.com/api.html) does not specify any requirement of 'secret' for using `app.use(express.cookieSession());` but when using the same in express it calls for 'secret option required. Why?

Even when I provide secret `app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: 'abc'}));` the following error shows in browser:-

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sess' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use cookies without supplying a crypting key and secret. You can either pass the secret in the cookie parser, or you can be more elaborate and pass all the necessary values when setting up session management. The latter offers greater control and as such is usually the best idea.

```
...
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({
  key: "mysite.sid.uid.whatever",
  secret: process.env["SESSION_SECRET"],
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 2678400000 // 31 days
  },
}));
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession());
```

Comment: Directly mentioning the secret as text will allow to read the cookies